# Aws lambda running out of memory

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, .net-6.0

I am running an aws lambda (dotnet6 runtime) that gathers information from several databases, serializes it, and exports it to an S3 bucket.

Despite changing memory configuration (up to 10240 MB), cloudwatch logs still report *Out of Memory*. The code in question contains a method that runs a loop of sql connections in using blocks, and I have realized that this error shows up after 1500 iterations approximately. Even if I skip code ran before this method, the error still happens at the same iteration.

Here is the relevant code:

```
public async Task FunctionHandler(ILambdaContext context)
{
    context.Logger.LogInformation($"Date: {DateTime.UtcNow:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}");
    try
    {            
        List<Empresa> empresas = _servicioEmpresa.ObtenerInformacionBasica();
        _servicioEmpresa.ObtenerInformacionEmpresas(empresas, context);                        

        await GuardarJSonEnS3(JsonSerializer.Serialize(empresas), "empresas", context);            
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        context.Logger.LogError($"FunctionHandler - {ex}");
    }       
}

public List<Empresa> ObtenerInformacionBasica()
    {
        List<Empresa> empresas = new();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_cadenaConexionCentral))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("aws_Analytics_Obtener_Empresas", connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        //fill object
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return empresas;
    }

public void ObtenerInformacionEmpresas(List<Empresa> empresas, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        foreach (Empresa empresa in empresas)
        {
            context.Logger.LogInformation($"FunctionHandler::ObtenerInformacionEmpresas::Empresa - {empresa.Nombre}");
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(empresa.CadenaConexion))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("aws_Analytics_Obtener_Informacion_Empresa", connection))
                    {
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        connection.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                //fill object
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }                   
            }               
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                   
                context.Logger.LogError($"FunctionHandler::ObtenerInformacionEmpresas - {ex}");
                throw;
            }
        }                        
    }
```

By knowing the list that comes as parameter, with that logger at line 5 I can see that the error happens at iteration number 1500 aprox (out of 1700 items).

Here are some logs from cloudwatch that illustrate the issue:
[image]

As the error suggest, it seems like a memory issue but the max memory usage does not surpass the lambda memory size. As stated before, I have tried max memory configuration and timeout (15 minutes).

Moreover, the lambda runs like a charm on local machine (Windows 10) through mock lambda test tool.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, you haven't provided enough information for us to suggest what might be causing the problem. Perhaps you can add some debugging code that can explain what your code was doing at the time of the error. The log you show says `Max Memory Used: 226 MB` so the error message might be coming from some other system or some other bit of code, since this is saying that the Lambda function did not run out of memory. What printed "Out of memory"?

Comment: Thanks for your response @JohnRotenstein. I've added more context to the question, unfortunately, I can't include business info logs to it as it contains sensible information. But everything related to the issue has been included in the question.

Comment: Instead of 1500 loops, first make sure that this database connection code works fine if there is only one record. If that works, later focus on running this code in loop.

Comment: Which line is generating the error? The actual "Out of memory" error might be coming from some code you are calling, rather than the Lambda function itself.

Comment: Thanks for the response @AnkushJain. I have changed the list parameter a few times to make sure that all sql connections did work, and indeed they did, so I don't think its SQL related, unless i'm missing something.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein there is no specific line causing the error, in fact, the catch block is not even hit. The out of memory error is coming from aws lambda.

Comment: The point I am trying to make here is to be 100% sure that your lambda function works fine when there is only one record in the list.  Have you tested it?

Comment: Yes @AnkushJain, I have also tested a thousand records since the item where the issue appears is item nº 1700 aprox and it works just fine.

Comment: Are you maintaining a global variable, list or string, where you keep on appending items? That will also occupy memory and you may run out of memory.

Comment: No, that list comes from a method(queries to retrieve this list) in the function handler, right before the method I posted is called. I'll edit the question to add this code as well.